# Report document class - each chapter after the title page resets to 1 why?

Tags: report

I am using the Report document class. But the page counter is off. In Chapter 2 the title page number is next page after end of Chapter 1 but then the content resets to page 1. The next Chapter after that same thing happens.

How do I correct this?

Comment: I have realised I have an Abstract (using \begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}) in Chapters 2+ which is resetting the page numbers. Anyway that can use abstract while not resetting the page numbers? I could of course just have this as normal text instead...

Comment: Welcome. // I suggest to create a separate file, mimic its chapter structure and replace content by blindtext (see said package). Once you can reproduce your problem, EDIT your question and add your simplified code.

Comment: abstract internally use the titlepage environment (a bit curious design choice imho) and that resets the page number. You could try `\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}`, or redefine the abstract environment.

Comment: Sorted it with:  \section*{Abstract} and then on next line:
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Abstract}  this means report class treats as main body text and adds to TOC. Paper-based dissertation writers please note!